# How do I change my location to a network share in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I want to be able to set my location to a network share in the PowerShell command window. I had thought that doing something like \\SERVERNAME\SHARE_NAME would do the trick, but it doesn't. So how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set-Location //server/share
```

Or, using the alias `cd`

```
cd //server/share
```

Note:  you may also use `Set-LocationEx` in place of `Set-Location`.

Comment: Oh, maybe that's what I was doing wrong. I was doing \\server\share. You're saying I should use //server/share. I'll give that a try.

That worked, thank you!